# Python Tkinter Letting Tk cover entire screen (like fullscreen)

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, resize, fullscreen

Is there a way to use tkinter's Tk() frame with a canvas in a way that it covers the entire screen but doesnt get bigger than the screen.
I mean it shall be similar to fullscreen.
If this is a part of my code:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
```

How would I achieve this? I think it is something with:

```
self.canvas.attributes(width=x)
```

Also: How would I now how big the canvas currently is (considering I don't save it in a variable)? Is there some kind of method or attribute of Canvas I could access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the `self.canvas.pack()` to `self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)`
then the canvas will fill the entire window.